# How to deploy a farm feature?

Tags: feature-activation

I need to create and deploy a farm feature to my SharePoint 2010 install. I have an event receiver that handles the ListAdded event. How do I deploy this to SharePoint as a farm feature?

With site and site collection features, I create a folder under 14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES and put a Feature.xml and any other config files that are needed into that folder. Then I add the feature .dll to the GAC and enable the feature through the web interface. Is it the same for farm features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SharePoint 2010 you shouldn't be creating folders under the SharePoint Root (14 folder) directly, nor manually copying files to the GAC. You should be using Visual Studio 2010 to handle folder creation.

If you don't have access to that, use WSPBuilder to create solution files which will be uploaded and deployed to each web front end in your farm.

As for Farm Feature deployment, they are deployed in the same way as any other feature but the Scope is set to Farm rather than SiteCollection or Site.